# Images stopped loading on heroku

Tags: image, compiler-errors, production-environment

My Heroku app uses an image uploader for attaching images to a form. The images were saving and displaying on the page just fine, but then all of the sudden they won't load.

Sometimes the console says this:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
```

And sometimes it says this:

```
GET https://safe-inlet-93558.herokuapp.com/uploads/grant/image/9/banner_banner_DSC_00134272684.jpg 404 (Not Found)
```

The heroku log says this:

```
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/uploads/grant/image/10/robot9324566.jpg"
```

Here is my production.rb file:

```
config.public_file_server.enabled = ENV['RAILS_SERVE_STATIC_FILES'].present?  
config.assets.compile = false
```

I have tried setting config.assets.compile to true, and config.serve_static_assets to true, but it made no difference.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this same issue by changing my image extension from .jpg to .png